# Adding Object to empty array in redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

guys how to append an object to an empty array in redux toolkit? I have set a
`currentTimeOfServices:[]`
in my slice then I dispatch an action with a payload
`dispatch(userActions.getCurrentTime({ startTime: startTime, name: item }));`
In my getCurrenTtime reducer I don't understand how to append this item.

```
getCurrentTime: (state, action) => {
      state.currentTimeOfServices = [
        ...state.currentTimeOfServices,
        { startTime: action.payload.startTime, name: action.payload.name },
      ];
    }
```

This is wrong and I know that but I want to know how to add/append an object to this currentTimeOfServices empty array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Redux Toolkit uses Immer inside, which lets you "mutate" the existing state with normal JS syntax.  So, all you need is:

`state.currentTimeOfServices.push(newItem)`

What you've got there is valid for a hand-written immutable update, but it's not necessary here.

See the docs for more details:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-8-modern-redux#immutable-updates-with-immer
- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers